# jQuery applying height from data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply the height from the data attributes onto the divs, this only works for the first one as the second div gets the same height from the first element. Does anyone know of a way around this do I need to run it as an each function for example?

https://jsfiddle.net/y45rgsza/

```
var $elements = {
   button: $('.js-show-more'),
   container: $('.js-readmore-container'),
   blockheight: $('.js-block-height')
};


var maxheight = $elements.container.height();
var height = $elements.blockheight.data('height');

if (maxheight > 5) {
   $elements.blockheight.css("height", height);
}
```

Comment: what check is this for `maxheight > 5`.

Comment: Its for read more functionality I just removed a few things and stripped it back so its easier to understand

Comment: you are missing the selector's context, use `.css(prop, callback)` see the answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `.css(prop, callback)` like this:

```
$elements.blockheight.css("height", function(){
    return $(this).data('height') //return the current elements data attribute value.
});
```

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y45rgsza/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$elements.blockheight.height(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate and set

```
var $elements = {
    button: $('.js-show-more'),
    container: $('.js-readmore-container')
};

$elements.container.height(function (i, height) {
    var bheight = $(this).find('.js-block-height').data('height');
    return bheight < height ? bheight : height
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aeck6ggb/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple get all elements with class `js-block-height` and iterate :

```
var elements=$(".js-block-height");
elements.each(function(){
   $(this).css("height",$(this).data("height")); 
});
```

Fiddle  : https://jsfiddle.net/y45rgsza/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use each function to check each and every container to get data attributes and apply inside blockheight.

Here is new working code,

```
var $elements = {
button: $('.js-show-more'),
container: $('.js-readmore-container'),
blockheight: $('.js-block-height')};
$($elements.container).each(function(){
var maxheight = $(this).height();
var height = $(this).find($elements.blockheight).data('height');
if (maxheight > 5) {
$(this).find($elements.blockheight).css("height", height);
}});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y45rgsza/6/